# mapping all possible implementations of an interface the same way

Tags: java, interface, modelmapper

I have an interface Source and a class Dest:

```java
public interface Source {
    int getFoo();
}
```

```java
@Data
public class Dest {
    private int bar;
}
```

And I have some code that uses modelmapper to map from Source to Dest:

```java
public class MyMapper {
    private ModelMapper mapper;

    public MyMapper() {
        mapper = new ModelMapper();

        mapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<Source, Dest>() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                map().setBar(source.getFoo());
            }
        });
    }

    public Dest map(Source source) {
        return mapper.map(source, Dest.class);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The following test is red:

```java
public class MyMapperTest {
    @Test
    public void testMyMapper() {
        MyMapper subject = new MyMapper();

        Source s = new SourceImpl();

        Dest d = subject.map(s);

        assertEquals(s.getFoo(), d.getBar());
    }
}
```

`d.getBar()` returns 0. It's as if modelmapper is ignoring my config?

Is there a way to make this mapping work for all possible implementations of Source (obviously ignoring any additional properties these implementations might have), in a way that I do not have to enumerate all the implementations when configuring the mapper?

For completeness' sake, here's the SourceImpl used in the test:

```java
public class SourceImpl implements Source {
    @Override
    public int getFoo() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: `mapper.typeMap(Source.class, Dest.class).addMappings(m -> m.map(Source::getFoo,Dest::setBar)).include(SourceImpl.class, Dest.class);`  ModelMapper added include() for inheritance

Comment: But that way, I end up writing `.include(SourceImpl1.class, Dest.class).include(SourceImpl2.class, Dest.class).include(SourceImpl3.class, Dest.class).include(SourceImpl4.class, Dest.class).include(SourceImpl5.class, Dest.class).include(SourceImpl6.class, Dest.class).include(SourceImpl7.class, Dest.class).include(SourceImpl8.class, Dest.class).include(SourceImpl9.class, Dest.class).include(SourceImpl10.class, Dest.class)`, which is not what I want. That's what I meant when I said "in a way that I do not have to enumerate all the implementations". Remember the "O" in SOLID!